# Converting Image Python code to C#

Tags: c#, python, image

I'm attempting to try and port the following Python code to C#.

```
import Image, base64, StringIO
def pngstore(input):
    input = open(input, "r").read()
    pixels = len(input) / 3

    img = Image.new("RGB", (pixels, 1), (0,0,0))

    bytes = []
    for character in input:
        bytes.append(ord(character))

    while len(bytes) % 3 > 0:
        bytes.append(0)

    for x in range(0, pixels):
        img.putpixel((x, 0), (bytes[x*3], bytes[x*3 + 1], bytes[x*3 + 2]))

    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(output, format="PNG")
    output.seek(0)

    return base64.b64encode(output.read())
```

The `while()` loop where it's appending 0 to the `byte`, `img.putpixel` and the appending of the `ord(character))` is where I'm a little confused.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FD.FileName);
long pixels = file.Length / 3;
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);

Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(fileToOpen));
while (bytes.Length % 3 > 0)
{
    bytes.CopyTo(?); // ?
}

foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, (int)pixels))
{
    //Color color = Color.FromArgb(, 0, 0, 0);
    //image.SetPixel(x, 0, color);
}

image.Save("newfile.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for loop with `bytes.append(ord(character))` converts characters from input to numerical values. C# reads bytes right away as numerical values via `File.ReadAllBytes()`.

The while loop ensures that `bytes` has length divisible by 3. It pads the list by zeros. [`Array.Resize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) is probably the way to go. I think it is the best solution to [padding an existing array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12716897/2157640). I think `File.ReadAllBytes()` cannot be forced to add the padding nor fill an existing array.

The whole image is just one row of pixels. The loop with `img.putpixel()` walks the image from left to right and sets color of the current pixel to the color with RGB channels set to values of corresponding bytes. Alpha channel is not used. Using [`Color.FromArgb()` with three parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx) is enough.

Another detail to fix: You want to initialize a [new, empty `Bitmap` with given dimensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3.aspx). `new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(fileToOpen))` could be simplified to `new Bitmap(fileToOpen)` anyway.

The final code (without Base64 encoding as you seem not to want it) is

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FD.FileName);
int pixels = (int)file.Length / 3; // int must be enough (anyway limited by interfaces accepting only int)

byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
if (file.Length % 3 != 0) {
    Array.Resize(ref bytes, 3 * pixels + 3);
}

Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pixels, 1);
foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, pixels)) {
    image.SetPixel(x, 0, Color.FromArgb(bytes[3*x] , bytes[3*x+1], bytes[3*x+2]));
}
image.Save("newfile.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer you want, but have you looked into [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/)? The compiled Python (MSIL) can run alongside compiled C# (still, MSIL) flawlessly. So you won't have to port from Python to C# and still can deliver assemblies that are indistinguishable to the average customer.

This answers not your question but it is a way on how to get things done by not porting at all. Obviously there might still be more profound reasons to prefer porting.